# How to mock system call with argument in whole directory?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mocking

I have a directory in my app which has several test cases.
Those test cases use some third party software using either `` or system calls.
And I need to mock those calls.

What I can't figure out is how do I mock those calls for that particular directory?

I had been trying [Test::Mock::Cmd](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/Test-Mock-Cmd-0.7/lib/Test/Mock/Cmd.pm)

But I can not figure out how to keep hold of the arguments that I provide for my system call and how to keep it across the directory.